# android problems connected to the socket on the WiFi was successful but not successful in 3g

Tags: java, android, sockets, url, httpurlconnection

I am making a android app that checks for connection to a PC via the ip and port.

I have a class that I pass the ip and port. Then I have a method to return a boolean if the conectivity is ok or not.

The problem comes the wifi works correctly but with 3g the method always returns true

The method like this:

```
 public boolean PingWithPort(){

    int[] AResult = new int[2];
    int countResOk = 0;
    boolean result = false;
    if(!hostName.equals("")){

        for(int positionResult = 0; positionResult < 1; positionResult ++){     
            try {
                    try{

                        Socket echoSocket = null;
                        echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, puerto);
                        echoSocket.setSoTimeout(1000);

                        if(echoSocket.isConnected()){
                            AResult[positionResult] = 1;
                        }else{
                            AResult[positionResult] = 0;                            
                        }
                        echoSocket.close();

                    }catch(IOException e){
                        AResult[positionResult] = 0;
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        AResult[positionResult] = 0;
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                AResult[positionResult] = 0;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }

            for(int controlResult = 0; controlResult < AResult.length-1; controlResult++){
                if(AResult[controlResult] == 1){
                    countResOk++;
                }
            }
            if(countResOk >= 1){
                result = true;
            }else{
                result = false;
            }
    }else{
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then how could solve this problem?.

Thank you very much. I taking days looking for a solution.

The solution I found is this:

```
public boolean PingWithPort(){
    int[] AResult = new int[2];
    int countResOk = 0;
    boolean result = false;

    if(!hostName.equals("")){
        for(int positionResult = 0; positionResult < 1; positionResult ++){ 
            try {
                    try{

                        URL url = new URL("http://"+hostName+":"+puerto);
                        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                        urlc.setConnectTimeout(3000);
                        urlc.setReadTimeout(3000);

                        urlc.connect();
                        if (urlc.getResponseCode() >= -1) {
                            AResult[positionResult] = 1; 
                        }else{
                            AResult[positionResult] = 0;
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        AResult[positionResult] = 0;
                    }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                AResult[positionResult] = 0;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
```

open an HTTP connection and check that you can open.

Comment: the ip are you trying to connect is a public one or a private one?

Comment: I have a public one, but I'm trying to connect one port of this public ip.

Comment: did you try to raise the timeout? maybe your 3g connection is high latency

Comment: The result is the same. I want to check if the pc behind that port is active or not but I have the feeling that the socket doesn't work properly with the 3g